# Oracle query for selecting sampling of number values from a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data field in my Oracle DB Table whose datatype is NUMBER. I have tried a query below using order by.

```
SELECT Value
  FROM Table
 ORDER BY value;
```

I am getting the result as

```
Value |
------|
1     |
1     |
2     |
2     |
3     |
3     |
4     |
4     |
5     |
5     |
6     |
6     |
```

Instead I want a result as

```
Value |
------|
1     |
2     |
3     |
4     |
5     |
6     |
1     |
2     |
3     |
4     |
5     |
6     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`row_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/ROW_NUMBER.htm#SQLRF06100) to evaluate if an occurrence of a value is the first one, the second, and so on; an `order by` based on this value and then for the value in the table will do the work.

For example:

```
/* a test case */
with someTable(value) as (
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual union all
    select 5 from dual union all
    select 6 from dual union all
    select 1 from dual union all
    select 2 from dual union all
    select 3 from dual union all
    select 4 from dual union all
    select 5 from dual union all
    select 6 from dual 
)
/* the query */
select value
from someTable
order by row_number() over ( partition by value order by null), value
```

How it works:

```
select value, row_number() over ( partition by value order by null) rowNumber
from someTable
order by row_number() over ( partition by value order by null), value
```

gives:

```
     VALUE  ROWNUMBER
---------- ----------
         1          1
         2          1
         3          1
         4          1
         5          1
         6          1
         1          2
         2          2
         3          2
         4          2
         5          2
         6          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. I'm using ROW_NUMBER() to arrange the values based on their occurrences,

```
SELECT VALUE
FROM (
  SELECT VALUE
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY VALUE ASC) RNK
  FROM MY_TABLE
)
ORDER BY RNK
  , VALUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

1 Value | ------| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 |

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY VALUE) AS RN, TABLE  .* FROM TABLE
```

2 Value | ------| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |

```
SELECT ROWNUM,TABLE.* FROM TABLE
```